# Lucene.Net Query with two MUST Clauses Returning Incorrect Results

Tags: c#, lucene.net, clause

I've created a query with two MUST clauses (and zero SHOULD clauses) that is returning results that satisfy only one of the clauses. As far as I can tell, this is incorrect behavior.

An example of such a query before searching is

```
{+(Text:wba) +(Attribute:10)}
```

The incorrect results being returned have 'wba' as a term in the 'Text' field, but do not have '10' as a term in the 'Attribute' field.

When I look at my index in Luke, go to the Search tab, and run this search

```
+Text:wba +Attribute:10
```

I get no results, as I would expect.

Here's a slightly simplified version of the code to run the search:

```
public static ScoreDoc[] Search( string searchPhrase, int maxResults, IEnumerable<string> attributes ) {

    var topQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    var textQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    using( var ngAnalyzer = new NGramAnalyzer( Version.LUCENE_30, 3, 9 ) ) {
        using( var stAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer( Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>() ) ) {

            var ngParser = new QueryParser( Version.LUCENE_30, IndexManager.TextFieldName, ngAnalyzer );
            var stParser = new QueryParser( Version.LUCENE_30, IndexManager.TextFieldName, stAnalyzer );

            var terms = AutoCompleter.QueryToTerms( searchPhrase );

            foreach( var word in terms ) {
                if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( word ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                if( word.Length < 3 ) {
                    textQuery.Add( stParser.Parse( word ), Occur.MUST );
                } else {
                    var parsed = ngParser.Parse( word );

                    var extractedTerms = new HashSet<Term>();
                    parsed.ExtractTerms( extractedTerms );
                    foreach( var term in extractedTerms ) {
                        textQuery.Add( new TermQuery( term ), Occur.SHOULD );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    topQuery.Add( textQuery, Occur.MUST );

    if( attributes != null && attributes.Any() ) {
        var attrQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        foreach( var attr in attributes ) {
            attrQuery.Add( new TermQuery( new Term( IndexManager.AttributeFieldName, attr ) ), Occur.SHOULD );
        }
        topQuery.Add( attrQuery, Occur.MUST );
    }

    // Actually conduct the search
    var searcher = AutoCompleter.IndexManager.GetOrCreateSearcher( AutoCompleter.TableId );

    var resultDocs = searcher.Search( textQuery, maxResults ).ScoreDocs;

    return resultDocs;
}
```

Here's an excerpt from the code that produces the index:

```
// Add the new document
var doc = new Document();
var field = new Field( IndexManager.TextFieldName, term.Text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED );
doc.Add( field );
if( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( term.Id ) ) {
    field = new Field( IndexManager.IdFieldName, term.Id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO );
    doc.Add( field );
}
foreach( var attr in term.Attributes ) {
    if( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( attr ) ) {
        field = new Field( IndexManager.AttributeFieldName, attr, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED );
        doc.Add( field );
    }
}
writer.AddDocument( doc );
```

So, to be clear, I'm expecting only results that match the text clause inside `textQuery` and at least one of the attribute clauses held in `attrQuery`. Why isn't this working the way I expect?

Comment: I cannot repro this. My guess is `IndexManager.AttributeFieldName` is wrong and doesn't match the field name used when the index was constructed. The code you have works as intended, though `textQuery` is not needed; you could've just added to `topQuery`. To know more, you'd need to provide the code that actually made the index.

Comment: @Setsu The textQuery can have multiple terms in it in the actual code, most of which will have SHOULD

Comment: @Setsu I added some of the code used to create the documents. `IndexManager.AttributeFieldName` is used as the field name during construction.

Comment: @Setsu I also restored the original complexity to the term parsing section of the search

Comment: Sorry I still can't repro your problem. I can only suggest that you work you way backwards with a simpler search method that takes 1 text and 1 attribute; if even that fails then there's something goofy about your index.

Comment: @Setsu Thanks for trying. Everything was working completely the way I expected before I added the attributes, and it's still finding results, just too many.

Comment: @Setsu I found it, it was something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
var resultDocs = searcher.Search( textQuery, maxResults ).ScoreDocs;
```

Should be:

```
var resultDocs = searcher.Search( topQuery, maxResults ).ScoreDocs;
```

Whoops.